# Is Wordpress fast enough for a heavy traffic project?

Tags: performance

I was always a WP guy, built many small sites with it. I will create a new community with a big fanbase and I was wondering if 3.1.3 is fast enough? I didnt have the opportunity to work with it since 3.0.

How does it react with heavy traffic web sites? Is it something that will make me worry enough to search for a lighter CMS or should I rely on it even with hundreds of visitors per day? I know about the tricks/tips to make it feels faster but is it by default ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is **any** considerably advanced CMS that you can throw high traffic at and expect it to handle it without any configuration effort.

Can WP be used for high-traffic site? Of course and it is being used as such by many sites.

But it should be WP on decent hosting and well-configured software stack, rather than WP on cheap shared hosting with Apache defaults and no caching whatsoever.

Comment: So Wordpress it is!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress is "fast" enough, out of the box, to handle hundreds of unique visitors per day.

WordPress, properly configured, can handle *hundreds of thousands* of unique visitors per day.

Comment: What do you mean by properly configured?

Comment: Depends on your setup, your use requirements, etc. But most often, would include some form of caching.

Comment: also very important is the hardware and this config, moduls of Apache; like APC and Memchached or an Load balancer for 2 servers; its give many possibilities to use WordPress on hightraffic sites, but all is depending on the requirements